# Diffeomorphism from the real line to itself.

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let

$$\mathbb{R}=\{(\mathbb{R},\phi)\}\quad \phi(x)=x$$
$$\mathbb{R}'=\{(\mathbb{R},\psi)\}\quad \psi(x)=x^{1/3}$$

be two atlases for the real line. Show that there is a diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}'$.

---

There is a theorem that says that $\phi^{-1}\circ \psi = x^{1/3}$ and $\psi^{-1}\circ \phi = x^{3}$ are diffeomorphisms.

What confuses me is that the exercise gives a "Hint" saying, "the identity map is no a diffeomorphism since it is not smooth". I don't understand the hint, even though I think my answer is correct. Can somebody explain why $id(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, id(x)=x$ is not an infinitely differentiable function?

Comment: The identity function is classically infinitely differentiable. The hint means you need to work with the definition of smooth involving the two indicated atlases, *not* the ordinary notion of smoothness on the real line. Work through those definitions.

Comment: My knowledge about differentiable manifolds is worst than rusty, but I think that the point is that $\psi(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. Similary, the identity have not to be continuous if the topologies are different. Here we have atlases instead of topologies.

Comment: @KCd So $\mathbb{R}'$ is not a smooth atlas because of $x^{1/3}$ behaviour at 0. So then the identity map from one atlas to the other would be the identity function composed with $\psi$ or $\phi$ which would not be smooth. Is that it? My problem is that I don't really have any definitions. My lecture notes are not good and I can only google random stuff online.

Comment: @KCd Nevermind I found the relevant definition! Thanks.